# What's wrong with my .hgignore file? (nothing is being ignored)

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket, hgignore

The content of my .hgignore file as follow and NOTHING is being ignored:

```
^nbproject$
^.htaccess$
^my.conf$
/media/images/captcha/.*\.jpg$
```

I tried to place the file in the main project repository folder and in the working directory.

What's wrong? Please help.

Comment: @Alex: I removed the git-related tags as they don't seem to apply here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line to the top of the file:

```
syntax: regexp
```

As for where the .hgignore file should go, per https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/.hgignore

> The .hgignore file sits in the working
>   directory, next to the .hg folder.

Comment: He said "main project repository folder" by which he means `.hg`.  He was correct the second time that it should be in the "working directory" which is the level above `.hg`.

Comment: Thanks, Ry4an. I always place `.hgignore` at the same level as the `.hg` directory. I added a reference to the documentation.

Comment: Yup, at the same level is correct.  He asked about in `.hg`, which won't work.

Answer (score 12):

You don't need `syntax:regexp` -- that's the default.

You do need to put the file in the directory above the `.hg` folder, so the layout looks like:

```
--yourepo
|
+--- .hgignore
+--- .htaccess
+--- .hg
```

You also need to escape all the dots in your file paths.  Try this:

```
^nbproject$
^\.htaccess$
^my.conf$
/media/images/captcha/.*\.jpg$
```

You do need to make sure you haven't already added and/or committed the files.  The `.hgignore` file does not override add, it only prevents you from adding stuff using wildcards and from seeing ignored (non-added) stuff in .hgstatus.  If you've already added these files you need to `hg forget` them before they'll be ignored.

If nothing's working try this:

```
hg status --all
```

and post the output.

Comment: +1 for very complete answer. Thanks to your post I learned that "The default syntax used is Python/Perl-style regular expressions." -- http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html#syntax

Comment: +1 because after more than 2 years this answer proved to be helpful once again :)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the simpler glob syntax for such basic ignores (with the `syntax: glob` directive to be explicit).  Also, you should technically be escaping the '.'s since they are special regexp characters, but you are lucky since '.' happens to match any character, including the literal '.'.  Confusion like this simply underlines my point about using the simpler glob mechanism, however.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that `hg` can't deal with the `.hgignore` file if it starts with a UTF-8 BOM. Since this is the default behaviour of Windows Notepad, you might need to watch out for that.

Comment: I'm going to assume this is why a user-specific ignore file crapped out on me after I pasted some lines of code from the windows console into it in Scite. That's just awesome.